# Term to packet erlang. Constructing a binary

Tags: syntax, erlang

I have the following code:

```
term_to_packet(Term) ->
    B = term_to_binary(Term),   
    A = byte_size(B),
    << 1:4/integer-unit:8, B:A/integer-unit:8 >>.
```

However, when I run:

```
term_to_packet("Hello").
```

I get an error:

```
exception error: bad argument in function term_to_packet line 20
```

where line 20 corresponds to the last line of the `term_to_packet` function.

I'm not quite sure what's throwing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B` is a binary, but in the binary construction on the last line you specify that it is an `integer`.  This seems to work:

```
term_to_packet(Term) ->
B = term_to_binary(Term),   
A = byte_size(B),
<< 1:4/integer-unit:8, B:A/binary-unit:8 >>.
```

Comment: No, for binary the unit defaults to 8 bits. (For integers, it defaults to 1 bit.)